# How to preserve types in query strings

Tags: node.js, get, query-string, http-post

Im trying to put together an API that would consume json data, and I'm having problems preserving variable types.

caveat: I'm using Node.js

Given the data:

```
{
  id: "string",
  data: [
    {input: [0,1,0], output: [1,1]},
    {input: [1,0,0], output: [1,0]}
  ]
}
```

When i make a jquery ajax post request with that data it is transfered as:

```
data[0][input][]    0
data[0][input][]    1
data[0][input][]    0
data[0][output][]   1
data[0][output][]   1
data[1][input][]    1
data[1][input][]    0
data[1][input][]    0
data[1][output][]   1
data[1][output][]   0
id                  string
```

or: `id=string&data%5B0%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=0&data%5B0%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=1&data%5B0%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=0&data%5B0%5D%5Boutput%5D%5B%5D=1&data%5B0%5D%5Boutput%5D%5B%5D=1&data%5B1%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=1&data%5B1%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=0&data%5B1%5D%5Binput%5D%5B%5D=0&data%5B1%5D%5Boutput%5D%5B%5D=1&data%5B1%5D%5Boutput%5D%5B%5D=0`

What I need to be able to do is decode the data on the server side but ***all the values of my arrays in data are being transformed to strings***.

Is there a technique for preserving the type of a value ie: "string" or "int" etc?

I'm currently using  the `qs` module on npm to parse my POST request body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery serializes any object passed in the `data` option of an AJAX request into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (just like a query string). What you want is to `JSON.stringify()` your object and pass the resulting string as `data`, along with setting the `Content-Type` as the previous answer mentions.

Remember that the `dataType` option specifies how jQuery should deal with the *response* to the request, not how to encode the body of the request (I've gotten burned by this one).

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a JSON server, set Content-Type: application/json in the POST request, so you'll be parsing an object rather than a string. The object will retain data types. Use req.is('application/json') on the server to ensure that the request is of type 'application/json'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, hope it helps.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint',                      
    success: function(data) {
        //TODO: do something with data   
    }
});
```